# Использование .bind() и оператор instanceof

Tags: javascript, prototype, bind

Изучаю книгу из серии **You dont know JS: cover this & objects**, Келли Симпсона! Возник вопрос по оператору `instanceof`! Не понятна следующая фраза из книги:

> Если вы используете встроенную утилиту `.bind(...)` для создания жестко привязанной функции, то у созданной функции не будет свойства `.prototype`. При использовании `instanceof` с такой функцией прозрачно подставляется `.prototype` целевой функции, из которой была создана жестко привязанная функция.
>   Использование функции с жесткой привязкой для "вызова конструктора" крайне маловероятно, но если вы сделаете это, то она будет вести себя так, как если бы вы вызвали целевую функцию. Это значит, что вызов instanceof с жестко привязанной функцией также ведет себя и в соответствии с оригинальной функцией

Вот собственно то, что я решил проверить:

```js
function foo(age){
  this.age=age;
  return this.name;
};

var a={name: "kristine"};

var b = foo.bind(a);

document.write(b()+"<br>"); //kristine

var c=new b(23);

document.write(c.age+"<br>"); //23

document.write(c instanceof foo); //true
```

Суть вопроса такова, что здесь не обычного? Ну создал я "конструктор" `foo()`, связал его "жёстко" с объектом `a` создал новый объект на основе конструктора, проверил этот новый объект, есть ли в цепочке его прототипов `foo()` вернулось `true`. В чём тогда суть того, о чем пишет автор книги? Просто данный автор славится тем, что разрушает "мифы" о Javascript, и вполне возможно, что я просто его недопонимаю местами, быть может он в очередной раз решил показать то место, где разработчики думают так, но на самом деле происходит другое! Просьба объяснить на доступном языке, можно даже с несложными примерами, тем кому не сложно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, автор имеет в виду, что .bind() возвращает ту же функцию, но с фиксированный this. Судя по языку изложения, вы используете машинный перевод.
Попробуйте перечитать оригинал, может, будет лучше понятно.

Comment: спасибо за отклик! Однако я думаю, что автор связывает происходящее с тем, что по сути своей из себя представляет функция `.bind()`, а именно `bar = function( ){return MainFunc.apply( obj,  arguments ) }` намекая на то, что функция `.bind( )` создаёт "сквозную обёртку" , для функции, которую мы хотим "жестко" привязать, и поэтому пишет, что у какой-то из этих двух функций (либо внутренней либо внешней, я не понимаю) не будет ссылки `.prototype,` хотя как мы видим мой код работает! Поэтом я запутался!