# Аналог bind( )( " жёсткой " ) привязки this, нужна помощь в объяснении!

Tags: javascript, bind, this

Код из книги Келли Симпсона **" You dont know JS: cover this & object "**:

```js
if(!Function.prototype.softBind){
    Function.prototype.softBind=function(obj){ 
        var fn  =  this,
        curried =  [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
        bound   =  function bound(){
          return fn.apply(( !this || (typeof window !== "undefined" && this===window)||
                                     (typeof global !== "undefined" && this == global)) 
                                                        ?  obj : this,
                curried.concat.apply(curried, arguments)
            );
        };
        bound.prototype=Object.create(fn.prototype);
        return bound;
    };
}

function foo(){
  document.write("<b>name :</b> "+this.name+"<br>");
};

var Aaa = { name: "Aaa" },
    Bbb = { name: "Bbb" },
    Ccc = { name: "Ccc" };

var fooObj = foo.softBind(Aaa);

fooObj(); // name : Aaa

Bbb.foo = foo.softBind(Aaa);
Bbb.foo(); //name : Bbb

fooObj.call(Ccc); //name : Ccc --//(1)\\--

// setTimeout(obj2.foo, 1000);
```

Собственно данный "полифилл"(ну не совсем полифилл наверное, скорее всего изобретение автора) предназначен для привязки контекста к выполнению какой-то функции (любой, которую нужно привязать), действует он так, что когда вы прописываете к примеру `foo.softBind(obj)` то функция  `foo()` вызывается в контексте переданного объекта `obj`, и данный вызов обёрнут в анонимную функцию, что собственно является аналогом встроенного метода `bind()`. НО встроенная `bind()` по умолчанию "жёстко" связывает функцию с каким-то объектом, т.е. . .

```js
function foo(){
  document.write(this.a+"<br>");
};

var obj  = {a:2},
    obj2 = {a:100}

var bar=foo.bind(obj);

bar(); //2

bar.call(obj2); //2
```

Как мы видим из кода выше, мы не можем переопределить `bar()`с помощью `call()` она всё равно будет ссылаться на тот объект, который мы указали для `foo.bind()`

В коде автора книги, как мы видим из строки `--//(1)\\--` мы можем переопределить `this` в вызове функции, даже после использования `softBind`, также данный метод (`softBind`) предоставляет возможность вызова функции с объектом по умолчанию, без потери контекста к примеру при вызове в какой-нибудь `setTimeout()`, в данном случае, с объектом `Aaa`, у меня вопрос по самой структуре этого полифила:

1. `fn = this`, `fn` в коде автора я так понимаю является функцией, к которой применяется метод `apply`, этот метод (аплай) же не может примениться к объекту, на сколько мне известно, но `this` всегда указывает на какой-то объект, в таком случае, что тогда такое `fn.apply()`
2. что значит `( !this . . .` , это буквально может значить фразу (`если объект контекста не передан. . .`?
3. только недавно узнал что означает данная конструкция, и снова заплёт - `curried =  [].slice.call(arguments, 1)`, я так понимаю она означает то, что (грубо говоря) мы делаем "псевдомассив" arguments носителем всех методов `Array.prototype`, и теперь ссылка на `arguments` записывается в `curried` , а цифра `... 1 )` означает, что мы НЕ будем учитывать объект, переданный в качестве контекста?
4. фраза `curried.concat.apply(curried, arguments)` из разряда "тушите свет". `curried` - массив аргументов функции `.softBind()`, так? `concat` - метод для объединения массивов, я так понял, речь идёт о `curried`, и аргументах функции `bound`, а `apply` тут для чего?

Просьба к знающим, объяснить прям по пунктикам моих вопросов, и если уж так получилось, что вы прониклись этой (не понятно зачем созданной) функцией, объяснить где оно вообще может применяться? Спасибо за терпение!

Comment: в чем принципиальное отличие этого вопроса от предыдущего?

Comment: @Grundby, эм? Предыдущего? Погоди, сейчас посмотрю, просто я этот вопрос уже два дня пишу, и уж почти наверное неделю как тут вообще не задавал вопросы!

Comment: Я про этот: [Использование .bind() и оператор instanceof](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/976016/186999)

Comment: @Grundby, у меня кроме этого вопроса больше не задавалось никаких вопросов в течении недели,  я тебя не понимаю!

Comment: Ссылка выше в комментарии

Comment: @Grundby, погоди, а при чем тут вообще ТО, что я сейчас написал в вопросе, и вопрос про Использование .bind() и оператор instanceof? Где ты вообще узрил связь между этими  вопрсами? Это во первых, во вторых, мне так и не ответили на тот самый вопрос про instanceof (кроме попытки парня с низкой репутацией), и в третьих, я ещё проверю то, что мне там пришили "дупликат" на правильность!

Comment: Как у тебя заголовок вопроса связан с телом вопроса?

Comment: @Grundby, Аналог bind( )( “ жёсткой ” ) привязки this, нужна помощь в объяснении! (скопировал только-что из вопроса, вдруг у нас разные заголовки!) Автор книги создаёт аналог .bind, я не понимаю, как работает данный "полифилл"? Блин я тебя чтот не понимаю друг, ты же вроде норм всегда отвечаешь на вопросы, а тут за 1 минуту ты прочитал вопрос на страницу, и уже правишь?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93218/discussion-between-grundy-and-muranx).

Answer (score 1):

1. В случае добавления методов в `Function.prototype` внутри этих методов `this` будет указывать на конкретную **функцию** у которой этот метод вызывает.

   ```
   fn = this;
   ```

   просто сохраняет данную функцию, чтобы ее можно было вызвать позже.
2. > что значит ( `!this ...` , это буквально может значить фразу (если объект контекста не передан...?

   Не совсем, в качестве `this` может быть передано что угодно, и в данном конкретном месте проверяется, что это что угодно при приведении к bool будет давать `false`. Далее в условии проверяется, что если в `this` что-то передали и это что-то глобальный объект (в зависимости от среды выполнения `window` либо `global`) - то функция вызывается в контексте заранее привязанного объекта, в противном случае будет использоваться ожидаемый `this`.
3. кроме `this` функция `softBind`, как и функция `bind` позволяет задать аргументы функции. Однако в `arguments` нет разделения на именованные и не именованные параметры, поэтому, для разделения `this` от следующих параметров, его передают как именованный, а аргументы получают с помощью метода `slice`, который в данном случае возвращает массив аргументов начиная с индекса 1.
4. `curried.concat.apply(curried, arguments)` позволяет добавить к заранее установленным аргументам, аргументы переданные при вызове функции. Так как `arguments` не итерируется методом `concat` по элементам и добавляется в массив, как единый объект, `apply` тут необходим. С помощью `spread` оператора данный код мог выглядеть так: `curried.concat(...arguments)`

Comment: привет друг, спасибо за ответ! по 1. пункту твоего ответа: `foo.prototype` это объект, я добавляю в `foo.prototype.a=10`, и создаю метод `foo.prototype.meth=function(){document.write(this.a)}`, здесь, в этом методе `this` указывает не на **функцию**, а на **объект** этой функции, поэтому я так и не понял твоё объяснение, `fn=this` получается это ссылка на объект функции, а не на функцию, поэтому я не понимаю (хоть убей), как получается что `fn.apply . . .` мы же можем применить аплай только к функции, но судя по тому коду который я привел выше, чтот не сходится!

Comment: по **пункту 2**. твоего ответа: не мог бы ты мне привести более абстрактный пример использования `(!this...` а то я что-то запутался совсем. Что этот `!` значит, что `this` приводится к булиевому значению? Или, что если мы к примеру бы передали в `apply` при вызове `0` или `undefined` или `null` то результат `!this` был бы равен `true`? всегда теряюсь при виде `!object`, т.к. единственное что я знал наверняка, что к примеру если  данный `object` есть в документе, то будет `true` если же перед `object` стоит `!`, то результат будет `false`

Comment: @Muranx, у тебя каша в голове с функциями и объектами. Перечитай пункт `1` там все указано что и как. По второму вопросу: `!true === false`

Comment: @ Grundy, мда, вот это уровень ru-stackoverflow

Comment: @Muranx, если у тебя есть конкретный вопрос, задай его отдельно.